# Recording audio with FFMPEG works in terminal but not through exec() of PHP

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, webcam, recording

I use this command to RECORD audio and video from my webcam in terminal and it works!

> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -sameq -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:0,0 -ar 22050 -ab 128k -y webcam.flv

But when I do it through PHP, like this:

> echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -sameq -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:0,0 -ar 22050 -ab 128k -y webcam.flv 2>&1 &');

I receive that log:

> ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers built on Apr 2 2013 17:02:36 with gcc 4.6.3 *** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED *** This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead. [video4linux2 @ 0x23579a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate Input #0, video4linux2, from '/dev/video0': Duration: N/A, start: 4868.729067, bitrate: 122880 kb/s Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuyv422, 640x480, 122880 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 25 tbc Home directory /var/www not ours.
>
> ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1401:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card [alsa @ 0x23589e0] cannot open audio device plughw:0,0 (No such file or directory) plughw:0,0: Input/output error

Before I got that Mic device problem I was having problem with the Webcam device's permissions, then i did:

```
    sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/video0
```

And the video capture was ready to be used! But now I got this Mic device problem!

I think it can be about permissions too, but I dont know linux very well and have no idea how to fix that!

Thanks!

---

## **I just found the solution! =x**

> sudo chmod -R 666 /dev/snd/*

Comment: # **I just found the solution! =x** #

> sudo chmod -R 666 /dev/snd/*

Comment: Please move the solution out of the question into an answer (though a little expanding would be nice). I'm also wondering if this question really is programming-related.